# how can i move a rectangle in py game without mouse and keys?

Tags: python, pygame

I have code to move a rectangle in pygame from left to right, up and down.
But I want to move my rectangle around the screen that I created..
can someone help me please?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
FPS = 70
fpsclock = pygame.time.Clock()


SIZE = (1000, 700)
form1 = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
WHITE=(255, 255, 255)
x = 0
y = 0
w = 50
h = 60
direction = 'right'
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            exit()
    form1.fill(WHITE)
    pygame.draw.rect(form1, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, w, h), 1)
    pygame.display.update()
    fpsclock.tick(FPS)

     if x,y==0,0:
        direction='right'
     if x,y==1200-50,0:
        direction='down'
     if x,y==1200-50,700-60:
        direction='left'
     if x,y==0,1200-50:
        direction='right'
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. This isn't valid Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first thing you have to look at is the spacing. Even though your code works (after proper indentation) the square goes out of bounds.

[image]

The same thing applies to y as well if the square should go up and down.

If you want the square to go around you just need to go left, right, up, or down at the correct time. So if you want to start at the left upper corner and go around you just need to check if the square is in a corner and then change the direction accordingly.

[image]

Keep in mind that going down actually increases and going up decreases y.

EDIT: 
Here you can see the result of my proposed concept
[image]

EDIT 2:
I've copied your code and refactored and completed it. I tried to explain why I did what I did.

```
import pygame 
# Only import the things you need it makes debugging and documenting 
# alot easier if you know where everything is coming from 
from pygame.locals import QUIT 
FPS = 70

# Use variables to define width and height in case you want to 
# change it later 
width = 200
height = 200

# I would group variables by usage, for example, I would group width, 
# height of the screen and w, h of the box so I can easily manipulate 
# the numbers if want to.
w = 50
h = 60

# Using an offset variable reduces the hardcoded numbers even more 
# if its 0 it will just move along the border but if it >0 it will move 
# the square to the centre
offset = 20

# You can declare it as a variable if you need the SIZE tuple somewhere 
# else, if you don't need it you can just set it as 
# pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
SIZE = (width, height)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED =  (255, 0, 0)

x = offset
y = offset
direction = 'right'

# This is just my preference but I like to have the variables that are 
# changeable at the top for easy access. I think this way the code is 
# cleaner.
pygame.init()
fpsclock = pygame.time.Clock()
form1 = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            exit()
    form1.fill(WHITE)

    # Try to avoid hardcoded numbers as much as possible, hardcoded 
    # numbers are hard to change later on when the code gets to certain 
    # size and complexity. 
    pygame.draw.rect(form1, RED, (x, y, w, h), 1)
    pygame.display.update()
    fpsclock.tick(FPS)

    # Don't harcode conditions, use variables so you can easily change 
    # them later
    if x == offset and y == offset:
        direction='right'
    if x == width - w - offset and y == offset:
        direction='down'
    if x == width - w - offset and y == height - h - offset:
        direction='left'
    if x == offset and y == height - h - offset:
        direction='up'

    if direction == 'right':
      x += 5
    elif direction == 'down':
      #Keep in mind going down actually means to increment y
      y += 5
    elif direction == 'left':
      x -= 5
    elif direction == 'up':
      y -= 5
```

Comment: thanks for your answer..but sorry, can you write the code for me please? because when i write , looks many errors

Comment: @sahelallah update your post with your updated code and the screenshot of the error. I will help you figure it out.

Comment: i do and share my newest codes

Comment: @sahelallah I've written the code, try to understand it